# Camera with a transparent View Scanner

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, expo

## Edit 1 :

please how can i masks the spaces between the card on camera ?

The overlay mask on left side of the card should be in light grey color.

The code down below is a simplified version of the snapshot.

```js
            <Camera
                ref={this.camera}
                style={styles.camera}
                flashMode={this.state.flashMode}
                {...{type, onCameraReady, ratio}}
            >
                <SafeAreaView style={[styles.cameraSafeArea]} top>
                    <View style={[styles.header, styles.maskFrame]}>
                    </View>
                   
                    <View style={[{flex: 40}, styles.maskFrame]} ></View>
                    <View style={[styles.grid]}>
                    </View>
                    <View style={[{flex: 32}, styles.maskFrame]} ></View>

                    <View style={[styles.footer, styles.maskFrame]}>
                        <IconButton name="cross" onPress={goBack} />
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={notImplementedYet}>
                            <View style={styles.snapButton}>
                                <View style={[styles.innerSnapButton, { backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary }]}>
                                    <Icon color="white" name="camera" />
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <IconButton name="flash" onPress={toggleFlash} />
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </Camera>
```

## My Css :

```js
camera: {
    flex: 1
},
cameraSafeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: StyleGuide.palette.transparent
},
header: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    padding: StyleGuide.spacing.small,
},
footer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: StyleGuide.spacing.small
},
grid: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    borderColor: StyleGuide.palette.white,
    borderWidth: 4,
    marginLeft: StyleGuide.spacing.small,
    width: width - (StyleGuide.spacing.small * 2),
    height: ( width - (StyleGuide.spacing.small * 2) ) * 2 / 3,
    borderRadius: 5,
},
maskFrame: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(1,1,1,0.6) !important',
},
maskCenter: { flexDirection: 'row' },
```

## Result Of This Code :

[image: photo]

I want to mask space between the whiteLine, for example in this photo (RightSide)

[image: frame]

Any idea how to get this done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```js
<View style={[{flex: 40}, styles.maskFrame]} ></View>
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%' }>
  <View style={styles.marginViewStyle}></View>
  <View style={[styles.grid]}></View>
  <View style={styles.marginViewStyle}></View>
</View>
<View style={[{flex: 32}, styles.maskFrame]} ></View>
```

CSS:

```css
marginViewStyle: {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(1,1,1,0.6)',
  height: ( width - (StyleGuide.spacing.small * 2) ) * 2 / 3,
  width: '5%',
},
grid: {
    alignItems: 'center',
//    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    borderColor: StyleGuide.palette.white,
    borderWidth: 4,
//    marginLeft: StyleGuide.spacing.small,
    width: '90%',
    height: ( width - (StyleGuide.spacing.small * 2) ) * 2 / 3,
    borderRadius: 5,
},
```

Comment: thank you for replying, actually u miss understood what i need to say. please could you take a look at the edition !

Comment: @algotourist oh. i thought i had read your question correctly, filling up the space with your mask layer (specified backgroundColor) instead of leaving it transparent. may i know what is the new screen after adding the above `<View />` components? are the sides still transparent?

Comment: after adding the above view, i got  : [Link](http://i.imgur.com/2lmIzxm_d.jpg)

Comment: @algotourist , can you try my updated answer? i've replaced the width with percentage values and commented out some values. let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yeahhhh dude !! it works, thank u for all your hard work on this.